# How to use group identities as estimators for SkLearn Cross-Validation?

Tags: python

Is there a way in python to run cross-vlidation without a given estimator (cross-validation from sk learn always requires one); or how could one only use the group identity as estimator (e.g. use gender to predict a depression score)?

Comment: then why don't you use simple regression with only one variable?

Comment: Oh my god, you are right, thanks! I must have had a serious black out. >.<